# how can i get all the FB graph id's associated with a domain?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

taking imdb.com for example. imdb.com has hundreds of pages with a FB graph ID (one per each movie)

I want to fetch ALL FB graph ID's belonging to imdb.com.

for example: the FB graph ID for http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1515091/ is "113109502056333"

I know this because I can "like" the URL, then using the "Graph API Explorer" I can see the ID of the liked URL.

Question: How can I get ALL FB graph id's of URL's belonging to a single domain? please use imdb as an example.

keep in mind, I do NOT want to send FB a batch of predetermined URL's. My website has hundreds of URL's and will not be able to compile a list of all URL's.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't! There is no way to get all OpenGraph objects that reside under the domain via Graph API or FQL.

OpenGraph pages are linked to URL and not to domain.